# Rechecked luggage for a connected flight on the same airline & ticket

Tags: transit, luggage, connecting-flights

I'm traveling from Jamaica to Cancun, Mexico via Panama. Do I need to claim my checked bag in Panama or will my bags follow me right through to Mexico? I booked the flight on 1 ticket and it is with the same airline.

Comment: Which airline?  Which airport in Panama?

Comment: It depends on which airlines your are flying and if they have baggage interline agreement between them. So specifying the airlines and the duration of layover in Panama will help.

Comment: **In general** (though International-to-any in the US is a notable exception, and probably not the only one), if the two flights are on a single ticket (with the same airline or partner airlines), your luggage will be "checked through" to your final destination and you won't see it. But as noted by the other commentators, the details of the airline(s) involved would help ensuring that this does not fall into one of the exceptions.